# Validar conexión a internet, pero me muestra error despues del primer clic

Tags: java, android

Tengo un **login**, y al presionar un botón ingresar, quiero que si no hay conexión a Internet me envíe un `toast` indicándolo, y si hay conexión entra a un método.

El problema está en que no tengo conexión a Internet y le doy al botón ingresar y me muestra el `toast`, pero al segundo clic entra al método en el que no debe entrar por que no hay conexión.

Dejo el código que se encuentra dentro del botón.

```
public void onClick(View v){

    progressDialog.setTitle("Cargando...");
    progressDialog.setMessage("Espere");
    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    progressDialog.show();

    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)getContext().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();

    if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isAvailable() && networkInfo.isConnected()) {

        // Si hay conexión a Internet en este momento

        iniciarSesion();

    } else {
       // No hay conexión a Internet en este momento

        progressDialog.dismiss();

        Toast toast= Toast.makeText(getContext(),"No se pudo conectar, " +
                        "verifique su conexión" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER,0,0);
        toast.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Estas seguro que no tienes internet, te sugiero cambiar a "modo avión" y probar el funcionamiento nuevamente.

Answer (score 0):

El código que muestras es correcto y debería funcionar sin problema, de hecho verifica si tu dispositivo esta conectado (`isConnected()`) y si esta disponible para estableces una conexión (`isAvailable()`):

```
 if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isAvailable() && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
   //Conectado a internet!
 }else{
  //No conectado
}
```

Si esta fallando probablemente estés teniendo un tipo de fluctuación en la red.

Puedes probar:

- Cambiando tu dispositivo a "modo avión" y siempre detectará que no estas conectado.
- Si tienes problemas de conexión en la red Wifi, puedes activar la red 4G para tener mejor disponibilidad, aunque recuerda que siempre toma como prioritaría la red WiFi y si no se encuentra se conecta a 4G.